# Why don't they try digging in Under the Dome?

Tags: plot-explanation, book-adaptation, under-the-dome

In the TV series [*Under the Dome*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_%28TV_series%29), the military used a MOAB (Mother of all Bombs) to remove the dome problem. In episode 2 one old man tried using digging tractor but Big Jim stopped him because it could explode. Why didn't they try digging into the ground? The military could use non-electronic methods, like lots of men with shovels. Is there any explanation of it in the novel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the beginning of the second episode (about 3 minutes in), several people are seen digging with spades, near Joe's house:

[image: Under the Dome]

Followed by this dialogue:

> Joe: Any luck yet?
>   Man: No, this thing goes down far.

As GµårÐïåñ's answer states, in the third episode Junior (being followed by Julia) go into the tunnels and find the dome goes really far down.

Comment: Shitt...i missed that scene......Now i wonder if dome is not a dome but is a sphere....might be possible.

Comment: Given that in the tunnels the dome is still going straight down and not curving back, I think it's unlikely to be a sphere.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat it is reasonable to assume that it IS a sphere; however, see my comment below on my post, it may be shallower on the bottom half circle, IF the smaller dome is any indication.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat But given that the smaller dome found in the woods (at the core of the larger one) *is* a sphere, it is far more reasonable for the large one to be one, too.

Answer (score 9):

As was revealed in the scene with Junior Rennie going into the tunnels in an attempt to find a way out by going under the dome, the dome extends down into the ground. For all intents and purposes, the assumption is that the dome extends down into the ground far enough that one cannot dig or if they do, it will extend into that void as well. However, I have to admit that seeing the smaller dome in the woods dug up and relocated to the barn, it would stand to reason the same should be doable with the larger dome, although probably to a much greater scale which might be out of the reach of the people inside.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the tunnel scene , i remember it. But using MOAB and not even trying digging from outside Millay looks silly to me.

Comment: I understand in the book, they tried to dig under the dome, but was unsuccessful. It is supposedly more of a sphere than just a dome.

Comment: @Paulster2 right, that's why I said that even if they managed to find a spot they could dig, it would just span into that space and surround them again. Seems anytime you have an opening it will span into it.

Comment: @Ankit They **DID try digging**, it was in the second episode. Near the beginning I think.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat but  Big Jim stopped that old man from using tractor because it can explode. But why not use Spade.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I added a separate answer with a screenshot.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ it's never shown that how joe dig into the smaller dome. But in that case Dome itself want this to happen.

Comment: @AnkitSharma correct they don't actually show how he transported it to the barn, BUT, the apparent look of it is not fully spherical. You can see the dirt at the bottom of it when it was dug up and also the void where it used to be is not fully dug down, fairly shallow compared to the upper arch of the dome.

Comment: *"However, I have to admit that seeing the smaller dome in the woods dug up and relocated to the barn, it would stand to reason the same should be doable with the larger dome, although probably to a much greater scale which might be out of the reach of the people inside."* - Well, that wouldn't be of use to anyone, though. All you could do with the large dome was to relocate it from the outside. But what would be the benefit of that? You still can't get in.